# Single-row subquery returns more than one row issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I have issue with this query:

```
UPDATE  ZOO.ANIMAL
  SET   ANIMAL.PRICE = ANIMAL.PRICE
           * ( select ANI_009.c1
               from   ZOO.ANI_009
               where  ANIMAL.TYPE = ANI_009.TY)
              WHERE ANIMAL.TYPE != 'familial'
```

when I run this I get this error:

> Error Reporting - SQL Error: ORA-01427: subquery returning a record of
>   more than one line 00000 01427. - "single-row subquery returns more
>   than one row"
>   * Cause:
>   *Action

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single-row subquery returns more than one row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381733/single-row-subquery-returns-more-than-one-row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error describes the exact issue. Your subquery is returning multiple rows. So you're trying to multiply the `price` by a set of rows rather that one other number.

The issue is:

```
select ANI_009.c1
from   ZOO.ANI_009
where  ANIMAL.TYPE = ANI_009.TY
```

Returns multiple rows rather than just one.

Comment: I would also add that this is a really bad way to write a query, exactly because the single-row query might return more than one row.

Comment: If you know you're querying by a unique key you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Basically In sub queries, when you are comparing your values please be sure about your query.

The error is all about, your query is

select salary from employees where salary = (select salary from employees where state like '%ne');

Here like operator fetches the list of records i.e.
new jersey
new hampshire
nevada

An equal to operator can only take one row from the sub query. In order to solve the above error please list only one record in the sub query